# How can I find out my posts (questions or answers) deleted (not necessarily last active) in the past 24 hours?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

Is it possible to find out all of my posts (questions or answers) deleted (not last active) in a time frame, such as in the past 24 or 48 hours?

**Let me emphasize again:**  recently deleted but not necessarily recently last active. For example, I have [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26091253/timeline) which was last active 4 years, 11 months ago. It originally had one upvote, and one downvote, and had no answer. Due to one recent downvote, it had a net negative score and was subsequently  removed by "Community (RemoveDeadQuestions)". But I can't   see this post  under my https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions. I was wondering what the awfully unclear criterion  is for what deleted posts are shown there and what not?

Comment: If you mean in general, maybe through SEDE (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678), but it depends on whether the deletion date is properly populated or not. There's some data erasure (including close date IIRC) for deleted posts.

Comment: Past 24 or 48 will probably not working with SEDE since the data is only update once a week.

Comment: Yeah, that's the main problem with that plan. The other alternative is the API. Brute-forcing URL combos just sounds like a way to get IP banned.

Comment: I guess it depends then whether that was just an example time frame, or the one the OP is actually interested in.

Comment: You can find your own deleted posts through your profile "recently deleted" or by using search (if you have enough rep)

Comment: Never mind, [the API isn't an option](https://stackapps.com/a/7660) unless you somehow track the status in real-time, but that requires 24-48 hours of continuous running to get the first results.

Comment: Relevant [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185492) by Shog9 explaining the recently deleted questions page: "So instead, we're showing a link (visible only to profile owners and moderators) on the Questions and Answers tabs that'll list the given user's deleted questions or answers, currently limited to those posted in the past 60 days."

Comment: These accusations of bullying have no place in your question, Tim. They are completely irrelevant to the actual question you're asking, so stop editing it back in. If you want to make accusations of bullying, open another question.

Answer (score 15):

All users can see their own *recently deleted* questions and answers.

#### Lists of recently deleted questions and answers are available from a link in your profile

##### For recently deleted questions

Go to [the questions tab in your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=questions). At the bottom, just below the list of your questions, there will be a link for "recently deleted questions".

> [image]
>
> [image]

The direct URL is: `http://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/<user-id>`

##### For recently deleted answers

Go to [the answers tab in your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=answers). At the bottom, just below the list of your answers, there will be a link for "recently deleted answers".

> [image]

The direct URL is: `http://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/<user-id>`

##### Posts deleted more than 60 days ago are not listed

Posts which were deleted more than [60 days ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/271271) will not be visible under this link, but it will display your recently deleted posts.

#### Users with >= 10,000 reputation can use search

If you have more 10,000 reputation you can use the search option [`deleted:1`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=deleted%3A1) to find all your deleted posts.

Comment: The obligatory crudely hand drawn red circles are a very nice touch.

Comment: @Nkosi thank you. And preview on mac always attempts to smarten those curves up! I will not allow it I tell you!

Comment: Just a note: The "deleted recent {answers,questions}" links only show answers or questions which were created in the last 60 days. The links do not show older questions or answers which were recently deleted. In other words, what is shown is "your recent questions/answers which are deleted", not "your questions/answers which were recently deleted".

Comment: @Makyen ahhh well that is interesting. Yeh, the op wanted a list of post that had been recently deleted independent of age of question. So they need a moderator for that or they can self query if >10 k