# Undeleting my own self-deleted question

Tags: support, deleted-questions, undeleted-questions

I ended up deleting a question I had posed on [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) and Git. I ended up deleting it hastily and the question is still relevant and unresolved. Could it please be indicated where/how I can do the undeletion myself or else should I message a moderator?

<sub>I do not know if this is the right place to post, but I do not seem to be able to catch the attention of a moderator elsewhere. Nor am I am able to see an option in any of my settings regarding this.</sub>

Comment: @cigien Yes, indeed I looked at that post. While the answer seems to indicate that yes, I can undelete it, I am completely flummoxed as to where exactly on the webpage I can go to find the "deleted question" and click/choose to undelete it. I tried "Help center and other resources", clicked on my own profile, looked at my previous questions, hoping to see this deleted question on top, etc., But I simply do not know where to find that question/url.

Comment: Oh, you don't have access to the question? Are you looking for https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389433 then?

Comment: @cigien Thank you very much! That was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: In the future, please include the relevant information (which is in your first comment) into the question itself. As currently worded, it's misleading as to where exactly you're stuck.

Comment: @cigien Why not now? :)

Comment: @Scratte There's no harm in doing it now as well, but it's not particularly useful. The OP's issue has been resolved, and the question itself has been closed with the appropriate targets.